# java storing instance variables and access using one of the key values

Tags: java, class, variables, constructor

I am currently learning Java in uni and I encountered this problem:

```
public class simpleStockManager {
    private String sku;
    private String name;
    private double price;

    public void newItem(String sku, String name, double price) {
        this.sku = sku;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getItemName(String sku) {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I have declared a class and some instance variables and I try to access to items using `sku`.
So if I declare 3 items in this order:

```
simpleStockManager sm = new simpleStockManager();
sm.newItem("1234", "Jam", 3.25);
sm.newItem("5678", "Coffee", 4.37);
sm.newItem("ABCD", "Eggs", 3.98);
```

When I try the `getItemName` method with `sku == "5678"` it should return `"Coffee"`, but it's returning `"Eggs"`.
I think it is the latest declared item that overwrites the previous item but I don't know how to solve this.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your `newItem` method overwrites all the member variables, you need to use arrays or lists

Comment: yes I understand, i am quite new to java, and can I ask how to store all the past variables in this case? thanks

Comment: As you are new to Java, please refer simple data structures like Arrays or Lists in javadoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each call to `newItem` changes the values of your instance variables.

You will always get the last values set by `m.newItem("ABCD", "Eggs", 3.98);`

If you wand to use **sku** as a key to store several variables you can use a `Map`

For example :

```
class SimpleStockManager{
    // The key of your map will be sku, 
    //and the name and the price can be for exemple in a Product class
    private HashMap<String, Product>  products = new HashMap<>();

    public void newItem(String sku, String name, double price){
        // A call to newItem will create a new Product and store it 
        products.put(sku, new Product(name, price));
    }

    public String getItemName(String sku){
        if (products.containsKey(sku)){
            return products.get(sku).getName();
        }else {
            return " Product not found...";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I understand, but may I ask in this case what should I do to save all the pass variables? thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer giving you an example of how to use a Map.